# speed up a handmade Cox model fit (v.s. `survival::coxph`)

Tags: r, optimization

Below, I compare the results from an R-function with my own code. The algorithm simply consists of maximising a function of many parameters (here, 19). My code defines the function and uses `nlm` for optimisation. Fortunately, both return the same result. However, the R-function is amazingly quick. I therefore suspect I can do better than using `nlm` (or a similar optimisation routine in R). Any idea?

---

Here is some [survival data](http://yaap.it/paste/4b838b930ffa7662#bsmoXJTO478UhWlduRY3esq2YZBD4B12DaVvwqUTRlI=) that can be fitted with a [Cox model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_models). To do so, one needs to maximise the partial log-likelihood (3rd equation in the wikipedia link).

In`R`, this can be done with `coxph()` (part of the `survival` package):

```
> library(survival)
> fmla <- as.formula(paste("Surv(time, event) ~ ", 
+                          paste(names(data)[-(1:3)], collapse=" +")))
> mod <- coxph(formula=fmla, data=data)
> round(mod$coef, 3)
    x1     x2     x3     x4     x5     x6     x7     x8     x9    x10    x11    x12    x13    x14    x15 
-0.246 -0.760  0.089 -0.033 -0.138 -0.051 -0.484 -0.537 -0.620 -0.446 -0.204 -0.112 -0.089 -0.451  0.043 
   x16    x17    x18    x19 
 0.106 -0.015 -0.245 -0.653
```

This can be checked by explicitly writing the partial log-likelihood and by using some numerical optimisation routine. Here is some crude code which does this job.

**The code has been edited based on the comments I received**

```
> #------ minus partial log-lik ------
> Mpll <- function(beta, data) 
+   #!!!data must be ordered by increasing time!!! 
+   #--> data <- data[order(data$time), ]
+ {
+   #preparation
+   N <- nrow(data)  
+   linpred <- as.matrix(data[, -(1:3)]) %*% beta
+   
+   #pll
+   pll <- sum(sapply(X=which(data$event == 1), FUN=function(j) 
+     linpred[j] - log(sum(exp(linpred[j:N])))))
+   
+   #output
+   return(- pll)
+ }
> #-----------------------------------
> 
> data <- data[order(data$time), ]
> round(nlm(f=Mpll, p=rep(0, 19), data=data)$estimate, 3)
 [1] -0.246 -0.760  0.089 -0.033 -0.138 -0.051 -0.484 -0.537 -0.620 -0.446 -0.204 -0.112 -0.089 -0.451
[15]  0.043  0.106 -0.015 -0.245 -0.653
```

OK, it works... but it is much much slower!

Does anyone have an idea on what is done within `coxph()` to make it so fast?

Comment: @Arun: I haven't tried Rprof()... but my code basically consists of one single line: the 'nlm' line...

Comment: Try typing "coxph" without any parentheses at the command line... enjoy.  I'm guessing it's vectorizing a lot of what you've done.  Try to break things down.  How could all `X[j, ] %*% beta` be pre-calculated before loop?  How could all the rows where `event == 1` be extracted beforehand?

Comment: @John: Thx for your comment. If I get it correctly, you think that I can significantly speed it up by re-writing the Mpll function more carefully. Right?

Comment: Keep this in mind, R generally executes individual calls slowly.  If you need a loop make it as small as possible because each call in the loop hurts you.  When your data isn't big using memory is much better than looping.  For example, that `if` statement is easily disposed of in the loop.  Just preselect the rows beforehand (but I think you have to be careful about j then... pre-create it as well).  Now the loop is much shorter and doesn't ask `if` each time... for starters.  I haven't examined it carefully but you might be able to get rid of the loop all together.

Comment: Have you tried optim for parameters optimization? It has few methods you can try, and in my opinion - it's fast :) http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html

Comment: I have edited the code to avoid the loop. This speeds up the code... but it remains slow :-(

@Java_xof: Yes, I tried... but in my trials it does not perform faster...

Comment: I was only being half facetious, you should have examined coxph, it's straight R.  `sapply` is a loop construct.  You should be able to vectorize everything here.  And if not, only loop over the looped sum function alone.  There's no reason for `exp`, `log`, and `-` to be in the loop.

Comment: @John: Thx; I will rework on that asap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version of your code.

```
Mpll2 <- function(beta, data) {
  X <- as.matrix(data[, -(1:3)])
  a <- X %*% beta
  b <- log(rev(cumsum(rev(exp(a)))))
  -sum((a - b)[data$event==1])
}
```

And here is a simple test of the run times.

```
data <- data[order(data$time), ] # No reason to order every time

# Yours
system.time(round(nlm(f=Mpll, p=rep(0, 19), data=data)$estimate, 3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.77    0.01    2.79 

# Vectorized
system.time(round(nlm(f=Mpll2, p=rep(0, 19), data=data)$estimate, 3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.28    0.00    0.28 

# Optimized C code
fmla <- as.formula(paste("Surv(time, event) ~ ", 
                          paste(names(data)[-(1:3)], collapse=" +")))
system.time(round(coxph(formula=fmla, data=data)$coef,3)) 
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.02    0.00    0.03
```

So, about an order of magnitude difference between each type. C is very fast, and you are never going to approach those speeds in R. But C is harder to write.

Comment: By the way, I still think it is important to sort the data set beforehand.

Comment: @Marco It is crucial that you sort the data, but you should do it only once, instead of every single time you run the function.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not understand your message. We agree then. That's why I sorted the data outside the function ;-)